# Publishing Firestore rules: An unknown error occurred

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

On a newly created project, I cannot publish any changes to the Firebase rules. Even simple changes like adding a newline to the end of the file or adding a space.

[image]

I feel like this may be a bug in Firestore but thought I'd ask here first...

```
Error saving rules –An unknown error occurred

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If something in the console is not working the way you expect, contact Firebase support directly.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: Did you manage to get this issue resolved?

Comment: I contacted Google support and we eventually got it working by updating the security rules using the Firebase CLI.

Answer (score 63):

I found that the `Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-origin` Chrome extension was the cause of this error for me. Disabling the extension fixed the error.

Comment: Really save our time

Comment: you are a saviour :)

Comment: CORS helps and makes us lost time xd. Thanks

Comment: really saved my time

Comment: Yes, when disabling it was allow to change rules. Thanks

Comment: Worked like magic. Tnx

Answer (score 3):

Install Firebase CLI in your command prompt, login in the firebase CLI, then open the .rules file with your editor(vscode, atom) and replace it with :

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

then deploy to firebase with from your command prompt with this command

```
firebase deploy --only firestore:rules
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue all of a sudden, "an unknown error occurred" for the Firestore security rules. Fixed it by updating it through the Firebase CLI.

So, in the terminal do the following steps:

1. npm install -g firebase-tools
2. firebase login // finish the login procedure

// Set up Firestore in your project directory, creates a .rules file

3. firebase init firestore

//Update the firestore.rules file that you can find in the root of the directory.

// Save and deploy your .rules file

4. firebase deploy --only firestore:rules

Answer (score 0):

The only way i got it to work is through CLI, Init it, chose the existring project you have and change the rules in the .rules file, then deploy them.

Answer (score 0):

Simply opening Firebase storage console on incognito and changing rules then, helped for me.