# How to modifiy rules in firebase storage without any issues

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm using firebase to upload pdf files , before that I should configure my store to make it readable and writeable
it tells me "Error saving rules –An unknown error occurred"

[image]

I tried to change it  , it did not work !

Comment: You can checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53404298/publishing-firestore-rules-an-unknown-error-occurred

Comment: If you're having unexpected problems with the Firebase console, reach out to Firebase support directly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53404298/publishing-firestore-rules-an-unknown-error-occurred